# Formatting and displaying date in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-datepicker

I created a datepicker directive which uses a jquery datepicker to generate calender.We can format the way it displays the data after selecting a date. I have some date which is stored in the database.
My requirement is to load the date in some specific format only when it displaying and don't want to change the model data.

I created a filter to format the text but it often returns "Nan Undefined NaN"

This is my filter

```
    myUploadApp.filter('cmdate', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
        return function (input, format) {             
          if (input) {
            return $filter('date')(new Date(Date.parse(input)), format);
          } else {
            return null;
         }
      };
   }]);
```

And to invoke this filter " cmdate :'dd MMM yyyy' " this is added.My input date format will be like this "23/04/2016".

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout moment.js - http://momentjs.com/

I use it to turn dates like this "2016-05-12T14:00:00.346Z" to words like "in 10 hours"

**fromNow.filter.js**:

```
myapp.filter('fromNow', [, function () {
        return function (date) {
            return moment(date).fromNow();
        }
    };
}]);
```

Check out to see if it has the formatter you require

Answer (score 0):

[Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) accepts string format `MM/dd/yyyy`, and your input likes `dd/MM/yyyy`, That's why it does not worked.

If you insist to use this format, need to correct the format before `parse`;

```
.filter('cmdate', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return function (input, format) {

        //swap month and date first
        input = input.split('/');
        input[0] = input.splice(1, 1, input[0])[0];
        input = input.join('/');

        var date = new Date(Date.parse(input));
        if (input) {
            return $filter('date')(new Date(Date.parse(input)), format);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    };
}])
```